# Excel VBA - Dynamic Range size

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to find the range on a separate sheet.

```
Dim abc As Range
Dim size As Integer
size = Sheets("Misc").Cells(1, Sheets("Misc").Cells(1, 1).Rows.End(xlDown).Count)
abc = Sheets("Misc").Range("A1:A" & size)
```

Im struggling to get the 'size' to give me the count of the rows correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to `Set` the range.

```
dim sz as LONG
with Sheets("Misc")
    sz = .Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    SET abc = .Range("A1:A" & sz)
end with
```

The row number should be sufficient. You don't really need a `.Count` for your purposes. Just find the last populated row by looking from the bottom up.

Comment: In his original `size = Sheets("Misc")...`, wouldn't he need to add `.Row`, or since `Size` was set to `Integer`, VB will recognize he wants an integer, so return the row?  I wouldn't think it would, correct?

Comment: The original formula was really only referencing a single cell, not a range of cells so `size` was only ever going to be one. The `.Count` should have been moved outside the last bracke, possibly as `.Rows.Count`. It was being used as the column parameter in the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx). Suffice to say that there was a lot going on.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Jeeped.